# Getting a syntax in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, syntax

I am trying to find the sum of the list in python; I have written a custom function and it is given below, I am facing a syntax error. How to overcome this

```
def summation(list):
  j=0
  for i in list:
    sum=j+list[i]
    return j=sum

k=[10,20,30]
summation(k)
```

Comment: You can't use `list` as parameter for a function, `list` is a **keyword** of Python. Your code has also logical problems.

Comment: @Marino it's **not** a keyword; it's not a great idea to shadow the built-in, but it's not invalid syntax.

Comment: What did you expect from `return j=sum`? You can't return an assignment statement, it doesn't have a value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, i mean is a built-in class.

Comment: To be clearer, one can use builtin types as names, but generally shouldn't because it clobbers the type for that namespace and can be confusing! Further, that's not the issue here

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code returns right after the first iteration of the for loop and returns an assignment which is invalid. This is what you needed:

```
def summation(list):
    sum=0
    for i in list:
        sum += i
    return sum

k=[10,20,30]
summation(k)
```

It would be better to name the variables differently, but this will work. Also a for loop in python doesn't iterate over indexes, it iterates over items. This means that when you say `for i in list:`, you get values 10, 20, 30 for your case, not 0, 1, 2 (the indexes). To get the indexes, use `for i in range(len(list)):`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Python Keyword as a variable name

try this

```py
def summation(_list):
    sum=0
    for i in _list:
        sum += i
    return sum

k=[10,20,30]
summation(k)
```

a better solution would be this, use the builtin sum function, it is much faster than a loop

```py
def summation(_list):
    return sum(_list)

k=[10,20,30]
summation(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never use built in keywords like `list` or `sum`. This will shadow your code. Next, your `for` loop has a problem. You are iterating from the values in the list, and not the element index. Hence, it will give you an error.

```
def summation(list1):
    j=0
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        sum1=j+list1[i]
    return sum1
k=[10,20,30]
print(summation(k))
```

I suggest you should go with the built-in `sum` fucntion.

```
def summation(list1):
    return sum(list1)
k=[10,20,30]
print(summation(k))
```